# Creating button rollovers with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rollover

I'm trying to make a function that I can use globally to create rollover states for images. Basically, I want to be able to add a class to an image, and then when you rollover it, jquery will use the same image name, and same extension, but add "-over" to the file name. (I'll have an image with the rollover state named the same as the non rolled over state except with the -over on it. I came up with this, but it's not working. Am I doing something wrong or does anyone know of a better way to do it?

```
$('.btn').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src").split(".jpg").join("Over.jpg"));
});
```

image:

```
<img src="/static/images/overlay-close-button.jpg" alt="Close" title="Close" id="our-staff-overlay-close" class="btn"/>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Is there any way to make it non specific to the file time, where it can figure out any file type rather than just jpgs?

I'm using:

```
$('.btn').hover(function(){
    this.src = this.src.split(".jpg").join("Over.jpg");
}, function() {
    this.src = this.src.split("Over.jpg").join(".jpg");
 });
```

and it's working great

EDIT 2: Can I also add an active state (when the button is being clicked)?

Comment: To make a similar thing for clicks, you can take the code in my answer below and hook it into the .mousedown (for adding the -over) and .mouseup (for removing the -over)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The splitting and joining should work as intended, you just need to set that back to the src attribute of the img:

```
$('.btn').hover(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    src = src.split('.jpg').join('-over.jpg');
    $(this).attr("src", src);
});
```

Also, if you want it to work with any extension, you could use a regular expression like this:

```
$('.btn').hover(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    src = src.replace(/(.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1-over.$2");
    $(this).attr("src", src);
});
```

The regular expression matches anything that ends with a period followed by one of `png, gif, jpg, or jpeg`, and replaces it with the first part (the path + filename), the string "-over", a period, and the original extension.

You can replace it back to the original state by removing the -over from the source:

```
$('.btn').hover(function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    src = src.replace(/(.*)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1-over.$2");
    $(this).attr("src", src);
}, function() {
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    src = src.replace(/(.*)-over\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/, "$1.$2");
    $(this).attr("src", src);
});
```

The `jQuery().hover` event accepts two functions, the first one is called when you start the hover, the second one is called when you exit the hover.

Comment: Your answer is really smart !

Answer (score 1):

You're just not doing anything with the result.  In this case you want to *set* the `src` (which can be done a few ways), here's the most efficient example (without changing your `.split().join()` method):

```
$('.btn').hover(function(){
  this.src = this.src.split(".jpg").join("Over.jpg");
}, function() {
  this.src = this.src.split("Over.jpg").join(".jpg");
});
```

Comment: Tried that, and nothing changes when I rollover the image

Comment: @Phil - Is this inside a `document.ready` handler. so the `$('.btn')` selector runs after the elements are present in the DOM?

Comment: I think it's because I had that code above the jquery file call, and it was saying that $.... is not defined

Comment: Yup... that was the problem. Works now

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr("src", this.src.split(".jpg")[0] + "-over.jpg");
}, function() {
   $(this).attr("src", this.src.split("-over.jpg")[0] + ".jpg");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider achieving your rollover effect using pure CSS.  It's really not necessary to involve script in something as trivial as a image rollover.  Plus, a pure CSS approach will still work for the paranoids out there who browse with script turned off.

Use the `:hover` and `:active` pseudoclasses and take advantage of [CSS sprites](http://www.google.com/search?q=css+sprite).

The downside here is that this method is harder to make generally applicable because you need to know the size of your images before-hand.